# Conda install local package fails

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to install packages in anaconda3 from a machine which does not have internet.

I downloaded the pkg.tar.gz package & ran

```
conda install pkgname.tar.gz
```

Then I get the annoying

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json):
```

& then it timesout.

I even tried the

```
conda install --offline pkg.tar.gz
```

I get

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pkg.tar.gz

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

What am i doing wrong ?

If i try to use pip from the anaconda few of the packages get installed, but this does not.

Follow up question

If i use pip to install a pakcage, would i be able to acccess it by conda & anaconda's python ?

Comment: I would try using and absolute file name and see whether that helps. See https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/#installing-packages-on-a-non-networked-air-gapped-computer

Comment: No, that does not work. I tried it.

Comment: Where did you get the file from? Did you download the file from anaconda.com? I just realised that all packages seem to be `.tar.bz2` files, but yours seems to be `tar.gz`, which is surprising. If it is a `tar.gz` with many packages you seem to have to unzip it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on downloading packages manually & then installing them only to find out that I need to download some more packages(chain dependency).

I found out another easier way of using conda-pack where you can build your environment in a machine that has internet(this reduces the chain dependency problem) & then .tar it, then transport it to the non-internet connected machine & then untar it.

More info can be found here https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/

I hope this solves time & effort for someone.

Answer (score -1):

You may find a way like this:

1. First unzip your .gz and get the .tar
2. Find your Conda env.

```
conda info --envs
```

3. Use conda activate according to your env e.g:

```
conda activate C:\SomePathGivenByCondaInfo
```

4. Use pip install with absolute path to ensure it:

```
pip install C:\downloads\SomePackage.tar
```